# S3Hook in Airflow: no attribute 'get_credentials'

Tags: boto3, airflow

I am using s3_to_reshift_operator at https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/operators/s3_to_redshift_operator.py and got the following error when I executed it:

```
AttributeError: 'S3Hook' object has no attribute 'get_credentials'
```

It looks like underlying S3Hook being used in my environment is different from one used in the repo. How can I get around this? I tried to upgrade Airflow but it didn't resolve my problem.

Comment: This is weird. Could you paste a pip freeze of your virtualenv and check what version of airflow you are running? Also are you providing a valid aws connection id?

Comment: It is weird indeed. The version is 1.9.0 (apache-airflow). I am not using virtualenv for this. The AWS connection ID I am using has this in extra field and worked fine in other operator (MySQL to S3): {"aws_access_key_id":"...", "aws_secret_access_key": "..."}. Type is set to S3 as well

Comment: Strange - if you look at the 1.9.0 tag of the git repository the s3_to_redshift_operator doesn't exist anywhere - are you sure that is the version you are using?

Comment: I should have made it clear that I copied it from a github repo at https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/operators/s3_to_redshift_operator.py. It relies on S3Hook's get_credentials method which is somehow missing in my environment. I ended up bypassing this issue but if I can get some answer on this, that would be nice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay so I think your issue is that you’re using the s3_to_redshift operator from the master branch (based on your comments) which is not compatible with the 1.9 version of the s3 hook. The s3 hook uses the aws hook as its base class which doesn’t expose the get_credentials method in 1.9. It does in master.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was fixed in the version 1.10.0. Right now in the `pip` there's only version 1.9. But you can install via `egg`:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/@1.10.0#egg=airflow[s3,postgres]
```

Comment: As of **Aug 27th 2018**, `Airflow 1.10` is [now available via `PIP`](https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow/): `pip install apache-airflow`

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue as well. Since I'm running on Google Cloud Composer upgrading to 1.10.0 isn't possible, but I managed to find a workaround by monkey-patching the S3Hook class like this:

```
# Monkey patch S3Hook
from airflow.operators import redshift_to_s3_operator
from airflow.hooks.S3_hook import S3Hook

class FixedS3Hook(S3Hook):
    def get_credentials(self):
        a_key, s_key, _, _ = self._get_credentials(None)
        return a_key, s_key

redshift_to_s3_operator.S3Hook = FixedS3Hook
```